# Swift Array Objects Disapearing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to initialise some objects in a for-loop, add them to an array and then access them later. What's happening is that the objects become unreachable for some reason and the array is empty.

Here's a simplified version of the code that I'm implementing:

```
class ClassA {
    var a : [CustomType]

    init() {
        self.a = []
    }

    func doLoop(jsonResults: NSDictionary) {
         // Breakpoint 1: self.a is empty (on first run) as it should be.
         for jsonResult in jsonResults {
             var j = CustomType(jsonResult["key1"], jsonResult["key2"])
             self.a.append(j)
             // Breakpoint 2: prints self.a with each j being correctly appended
         }
    }

    func retrieveItem() -> CustomType {
        // Breakpoint 3: self.a is an empty array!
        return self.a[0]
    }
}
```

doLoop is called first, and then retrieveItem is called. I have checked that doLoop runs completely before 'retrieveItem' is called.

Comment: Where is jsonResults declared?

Comment: Is the 'real' `doLoop` an async call to fetch data from the network?

Comment: Are you sure `CustomType(jsonResult["key1"], jsonResult["key2"])` is working? What are `jsonResult["key1"]` and `jsonResult["key2"])` actually supposed to retrieve - as far as I can tell, jsonResult is of type `Element` and does not support the subscript operator... If you "simplify" code, make you sure you don't break its actual functionality.

Comment: @Alladinian you were right. The solution was to use a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, if `a` is empty, then `jsonResults` is also empty.

Please check the length of `jsonResults`

Comment: Sorry - I have updated the code, and jsonResults is definitely not empty.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the return type in your `retrieveItem()` function. The function should be declared as `retrieveItem() -> CustomType`